# Model/Controller doesn't return true result in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, model, controller, return

I'm trying to insert data into the database.The insert the query is working fine, values are getting inserted but controller show else results always.

**Model Code**

```
// Function to add record in table
public function add($data){
    $this->db->insert('xin_employees', $data);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
$data = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),

);

$result = $this->Employees_model->add($data);
 if ($result == TRUE) {
 $Return['result'] = $this->lang->line('xin_success_add_employee');
```

Comment: seems like the comparison between `true` and `TRUE` is not the same, you might have define a constant named `TRUE` with a value that is not the same as `true`

Comment: but same code is working in another script

Answer (score 1):

**Model Code:**

```
 // Function to add record in table
    public function add($data){
       if($this->db->insert('xin_employees', $data)){
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public function insert($data){
    if($this->db->insert('student', $data){
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
  else {
        return false;
    }
}
```